# C# Insert CSV into SQL

Tags: c#, sql, csv, sqlbulkcopy

I am attempting to import CSV data into SQL, but when I look at what the program has tried to import, it stops after the first row and column. I assume it is trying to add it as a header, can I skip column header or does one need to be added? Thanks

```
private static DataTable csvDataTable(string filepath)
    {
        DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(filepath))
            {
                csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
                csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;

                string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
                foreach (string column in colFields)
                {
                    DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                    datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                    csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
                }
                while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                {
                    string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();

                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (fieldData[i] == "")
                        {
                            fieldData[i] = null;
                        }
                    }
                    csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return csvData;
    }
```

Comment: It could be throwing an exception and you wouldn't know it because you're eating it.  Don't silently throw away exceptions like that.  Handle them or don't catch them.  At a minimum, log the exception.

Comment: @srutzky the code presented only creates a datatable.  He would be passing the return value into `SqlBulkCopy`

Comment: @srutzky Thanks for the input, but your comment does not add any value. As Amy said, the return is passed into SqlBulkCopy.